# Como usar un action de un form en html

Tags: html, mysql, express

Que tal chicos tengo un problema, estoy intentando hacer un servidor con un register y un login y pude conectar toda la base de datos perfecta pero mi problema es que tengo un form donde hay 4 campos de input text y un submit y quiero que cuando toque el submit el form con el metodo action me mande una "ruta" y en express poder generar un router.post y que con esa ruta yo pueda agarrar los valores del input y guardarlos. El tema es que esa "ruta" que el metodo action genera nunca me la da. Este es mi formulario:

```
<form action="/register/add" method="post"></form>
        <p>Nombre</p>
        <input type="text" name="inputname" id="inputname" placeholder="Nombre">;                                
        <p>Apellido</p>
        <input type="text" name="inputsurname" placeholder="Apellido" id="inputsurname">
        <p>Email</p>
        <input type="text" name="inputemail" placeholder="Email" id="inputemail">
        <p>Contraseña</p>
        <input type="password" name="inputpassword" placeholder="Contraseña" id="inputpassword">
        <button type="input" id="inputbutton">¡Registrate!</button>
    </form>
```

Y el código en donde le pido la "ruta" al action para darle una respuesta es esta:

```
routes.post("/register/add", (req, res)=>{
    console.log("prueba");
```

});
¿Tengo que llamar al escript donde tengo el routes.post en el html?
¿Necesito alguna otra dependencia de express como bodyparser o alguna de ese estilo?
Estoy usando express.
Disculpen la ignorancia, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @Pedro Danderfer, en tu botón para enviar el form, debes poner `type="submit"`. De este modo hace el envió, sino no lo esta enviando nunca.

Comment: Fue un error mio! tiene puesto submit el boton

Comment: @Pedro, si lo tiene, edita tu pregunta y colocalo en tu código, de otra forma quienes lean tu pregunta van a seguir viendo que no lo tiene. Un saludo. Te invito a leer [mcve].

Comment: @Pedro Danderfer a menos que sea otro error en tu pregunta, tienes un error en las etiquetas. `<form action="/register/add" method="post"></form>` La etiqueta de cierre está de mas. Ya lo estas cerrando abajo de tus inputs(como debe ser). Saludos!